# VueJS: Deleting dinamically rendered component in array with splice() method based on provided index, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vue-component

**Context:**
I'm making a simple todo app, where you can add & delete items.

**Problem:**
When I click the "Delete" button on a specific item,  this happens:  it always deletes the last item in the list, instead of the clicked item.

**Implementation details:**
I have a parent & child component.  The child component is dinamically rendered with the help of **v-for** loop, when array gets populated. When button "Delete" is clicked, the child component emits a delete event to parent component. The parent component handles the delete functionality with the "detach()" method.

**Code example**
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-pine-nnbfo

I'm using splice() method in order to delete the specific component from array and though I'm providing the corect index of component that triggered the delete event, it always deletes the last component from array and I don't know why. Can someone point out the obvious, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using too many arrays when you only need 1 array - the array with ToDo items.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <label>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" name="firstName" v-model="firstName">
    </label>
    <label>
      Last Name:
      <input type="text" name="lastName" v-model="lastName">
    </label>
    <label>
      Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email">
    </label>
    <button class="btn" @click="add">Send</button>

    <Todo
      v-for="(item,idx) in todoItems"
      :key="idx"
      :id="item.id"
      :first-name="item.firstName"
      :last-name="item.lastName"
      :email="item.email"
      @btnClick="detach(idx)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Todo from "./components/todo";

export default 
{
  name: "App",
  components: 
  {
    Todo
  },

  data() 
  {
    return {
      id: 0,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      todoItems: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.todoItems.push({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        id: ++this.id,
      });
      this.firstName = '';
      this.lastName = '';
      this.email = '';
    },

    /** the delete function **/
    detach(index) 
    {
      this.todoItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```